# Cannot Join Counter Strike Go Servers

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Every server I try to join gives me the whole "Not Responding" bit so I went ahead and allowed it through my firewall as an exception but still no luck. Every single server is like this.

What are some other things that could cause servers not to respond?

Answer (score 1):

In some servers we need the allowance for joining the server, you may be trying to join password secured servers.
Other things can be:

- Slow net connection
- Bad server request
- Pirated version Game
- Some virus can also cause this

You will need to check all these thing before connecting to a server...